# np.where(df['[DO] Waermepumpe 1-Umwaelzpumpe'] == 1, timedelta64[ns], 0) doesn't work?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

have csv with an timestamp, an value and an "on" and "Off".
I want to see the difference in the "on" series.

csv:

| Zeit | [TE] Heizkreis 1-Raumtemperatur | [DO] Waermepumpe 1-Umwaelzpumpe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-01 12:01:30 | 20 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 12:02:30 | 20 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 12:03:30 | 20 | 1 |
| 2018-06-01 12:04:30 | 21 | 1 |
| 2018-06-01 12:05:30 | 22 | 1 |
| 2018-06-01 12:06:30 | 23 | 1 |
| 2018-06-01 12:10:30 | 23 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 12:11:30 | 20 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 12:12:30 | 20 | 1 |
| 2018-06-01 12:13:30 | 22 | 1 |
| 2018-06-01 12:15:30 | 23 | 1 |
| 2018-06-01 12:16:30 | 25 | 1 |

And I want to see how the difference between the curvs.

| Zeit | [TE] Heizkreis 1-Raumtemperatur | [DO] Waermepumpe 1-Umwaelzpumpe | change | runtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-01 12:01:30 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 12:02:30 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 12:03:30 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 60 |
| 2018-06-01 12:04:30 | 21 | 1 | 1 | 120 |
| 2018-06-01 12:05:30 | 22 | 1 | 2 | 180 |
| 2018-06-01 12:06:30 | 23 | 1 | 3 | 240 |
| 2018-06-01 12:10:30 | 23 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 12:11:30 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 12:12:30 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 12:13:30 | 22 | 1 | 2 | 60 |
| 2018-06-01 12:15:30 | 23 | 1 | 3 | 180 |
| 2018-06-01 12:16:30 | 25 | 1 | 4 | 240 |

And with every series I want an line with the starting time as lable on an plot, starting with 0 time and 0 change.

At first I made an df how calculates the difference between the timestamps:

```
df['Zeitdifferenz'] = df['Zeit'].diff()  
df['Zeitdifferenz'] = df['Zeitdifferenz'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
```

then an runtime over all:

```
df['Laufzeit'] = df['Zeitdifferenz'].cumsum()
```

and then I tried different things, the best was this:

```
df['Laufzeit neu'] = np.where(df['[DO] Waermepumpe 1-Umwaelzpumpe'] == 1, df['Laufzeit'], 0)
```

with that I want to set the df['Laufzeit'] at 0 and calc the runtime or so.
But if I insert the df['Laufzeit'] ( dtype: timedelta64[ns] ) I get the error:

```
SystemError: <built-in function ensure_datetime64ns> returned a result with an error set
```

If I enter an float64 dtype it works.

I hope someone have the time to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) using the `0` in "DO" to form groups, to then compute the cumulated [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) of time and the [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for the change:

```
df['Zeit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Zeit'])

group = df['[DO] Waermepumpe 1-Umwaelzpumpe'].eq(0).cumsum()

g = df.groupby(group)

df['change'] = g.cumcount()
df['runtime'] = g['Zeit'].apply(lambda s: s.diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0, downcast='infer').cumsum())
```

output:

```
                  Zeit  [TE] Heizk...  [DO] Waerme...  change  runtime
0  2018-06-01 12:01:30             20               0       0        0
1  2018-06-01 12:02:30             20               0       0        0
2  2018-06-01 12:03:30             20               1       1       60
3  2018-06-01 12:04:30             21               1       2      120
4  2018-06-01 12:05:30             22               1       3      180
5  2018-06-01 12:06:30             23               1       4      240
6  2018-06-01 12:10:30             23               0       0        0
7  2018-06-01 12:11:30             20               0       0        0
8  2018-06-01 12:12:30             20               1       1       60
9  2018-06-01 12:13:30             22               1       2      120
10 2018-06-01 12:15:30             23               1       3      240
11 2018-06-01 12:16:30             25               1       4      300
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't calculate the change from the Heizkreis

Comment: @Patrik.so I missed that, but what is the calculation to be made? I don't see a difference in the output

Comment: the same thing with runtime with TE, the 2. series starts with 20 and than 20,22,23,25 so the change should be 0,2,3,5 .

Comment: I changes it to: df['change'] = g['[TE] Heizkreis 1-Raumtemperatur'].apply(lambda s: s.diff().fillna(0, downcast='infer').cumsum())